# How hide/remove “created by” and “last modified” in view form

Tags: 2010

[image]

any information would be great, im trying to hide the circled section

Answer (score 2):

You can edit view page in SharePoint Designer and remove created and modified from the form.
second option

**Steps:**

1. Go to the list, choose **list** (close to files and browse)
2. Choose **form web parts** and **deafult display form**.
3. In the editor click **add a webpart** and find "script editor".
4. In script editor you can link to an css file (put the css file in style library and link in the script editor) or just put in the css code (remember the tags).

   <style type="text/css">
   .ms-formtoolbar{ 
   display:none;
   }
   </style>

Save this file in style library and refer this file in content editor web part on displayform.aspx.
check the image on how to go to display form in lists.
[image]

Comment: im  sharepoint designer, where do I go now?

Comment: find the edited answer above

Answer (score 1):

You can add either a content editor WP or Script Editor and link to the css here:

```
.ms-formtoolbar{
    display:none;
}
```